# notify-send volume popup replacing itself

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to have notifications on volume and brightness changes. I pieced the command together using the amixer part and notify-send part. The two parts works isolated but not together.  I think it has something to do with how the single quotes end the line ZSH or how the shell interpret quotation but I haven't found an answer.

```
notify-send --expire-time=50 "Volume $(printf %.0f%% $(amixer get Master | awk '$0~/%/{print $4}' | tr -d '[]'))"
```

exits with

> zsh: bad math expression: operand expected at end of string.

Also how can you make the notification replace itself with `notify-send`? . So that only one notification is visible at all times.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please use code tags for your posts and be clear in your question it is not clear at all by this post.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first post on SO. Therefore I need to learn the semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your printf statement. You are sending a string (eg. `"50%"`) to a printf statement that requests a number. This leads to somewhat cryptic `bad math expression` in `zsh`:

```
[zsh]$ printf %.0f 50.0%
zsh: bad math expression: operand expected at `'
0%
```

Under `bash` you get a different error which is a bit more understandable :

```
[bash]$ printf %.0f 50.0%
bash: printf: 50.0%: invalid number
```

The output of your amixer command returns exactly such a string. All you need to do is update your printf format specifier to output a string.

```
[zsh]$ printf %s 50.0%  
50.0%
```

This implies that the following should work for you :

```
notify-send --expire-time=50 "Volume $(printf %s $(amixer get Master | awk '$0~/%/{print $4}' | tr -d '[]'))"
```